# Outputting a String with PHP Code

Tags: php, string, eval

I'm building a WordPress theme using ACF that has a custom field for inputting code. When I build a page if it has a unique snippet of code I use the PHP code custom field and then need to include it as code and not just output it as a string. What's the best way of including this custom PHP?

The code that I got working so far was the following but after lots of reading everyone seems to highly discourage `eval()` but I don't know an alternative in this case:

```
<?php
$section_php = get_sub_field('section_php');

eval($section_php);
?>
```

Comment: Hands off from **evil** `eval()`

Comment: Well what kind of code is it you want to execute? Are those simple directives or is it more complex? If we know that we can present you some good alternatives to `eval`

Comment: Well… you want to execute a string as PHP code. There's only `eval` for that. The problem is not in `eval` per se, it's that you want to **execute an arbitrary string as code.** You shouldn't do *that*. If that's explicitly what you want to do, use `eval`. But you should rather reevaluate your life choices that let you to wanting this in the first place.

Comment: can you paste a dump of `$section_php` ?

Comment: If you want to output something, why not use `echo`?

Comment: The problem is each page has unique needs / needs may change as more pages are added / content changes. Here's the example code

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        //'user_agent '  => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100301 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.6",
        'header' => array(
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8
'
        ), 
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$f = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com", false, $context);
echo $f;

Comment: So why don't you wan't to create set of classes with methods and detect what kind of method to execute depending on page's type?

Answer (score -2):

Use call_user_func instead of eval because of the fact that call_user_func can only call one user function. eval on the other hand executes the string as PHP code itself.

Comment: And what if the returned value is not the name of a function?

Comment: And what if the function is `eval`…?

Comment: I'm looking at using it for call_user_func(get_sub_field('section_php')).  Will that not work executing his ECHO?